# I cannot figure out how to find the factorial of a number. Can anyone help me do this in recursion and using sequential programming?

Tags: python, factorial

Here is my code:

```
def menu():
    print ("Would you like to find the factorial of this number using \n    Option 1: sequential programming? \n Option 2: recurion?")
    choice = input("Enter the number of your preferred option: ")
    if (choice >= 1) and (choice <= 2):
        return choice
    else:
        print ("That is not an option.")

def recur_factorial(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        fact = (n) * (recur_factorial(n - 1))
        print fact
        return

def main():
    number = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
    if number < 0:
        print ("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers.")
    else:
        choice = menu()
        if choice == 1:
            if number == 0:
               print 1
            else:
               for i in range(1,number + 1):
                   answer = factorial * (i)
                   print answer
        else:
            recur_factorial(number)

main()
```

I am trying to get the factorial of a number two different ways. Option 1 should use sequential programming. When I use option 1 right now thought I get the error: global name 'factorial' not defined. When I use option 2 (which should be recursion), I get the error :unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'. Any suggestions on how to fix this? I am using the Python language.

The full error I receive with Option 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/project4", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/project4", line 28, in main
    answer = factorial * (i)
 NameError: global name 'factorial' is not defined
```

The full error I receive with Option 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/project4", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/Documents/project4", line 31, in main
    recur_factorial(number)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/project4", line 13, in recur_factorial
    fact = (n) * (recur_factorial(n - 1))
  File "/Users/user/Documents/project4", line 13, in recur_factorial
    fact = (n) * (recur_factorial(n - 1))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of the errors you are getting. They include valuable information, including which line the error is occurring on.

Answer (score 1):

On Python, if a function doesn't return anything, it returns a NoneType, which is the Object type for None. In your case, the recur_factorial function isn't returning anything, so you cannot multiply the integer (n) with a NoneType (recur_factorial(n - 1)). A working version should be:

```
   def recur_factorial(n):
        if n == 1 or n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n * recur_factorial(n - 1)
```

That way, executing

```
print recur_factorial(5)
```

would output

```
120
```

Recursion functions should always return a call to itself with a parameter that's closer to the base case than the current value when the call isn't the base case itself.

Answer (score 0):

For option 1, on the line near the bottom:

```
answer = factorial * (i)
```

You have not previously defined `factorial`, and I believe it should actually be changed to `answer`. Try adding `answer = 1` right before the `for` loop and changing that line to `answer = answer * i` or, more simply, `answer *= i`.

For option 2, you will need to return the result of the factorial. Change `return` to `return fact`.